# Why am I getting a full and an incremental backup on the same day?

Tags: windows-10, backup, acronis-trueimage, incremental-backup

On Acronis Advanced Backup 11.7.44421, given these backup rules

[image]

I get two backups, one incremental at 3am and a full at 4am, on the first Sunday of the month:

[image]

This last sunday, the computer slept unplugged and without the backup drive attached. When I woke it up it also tried to run both full and incremental backups (ignore the name of the job, which says 3AM):

[image]

**Why isn't the 1st vs every other Sunday of the month rule working?**

PS: *If the machine is turned off, run the missed tasks at startup* is checked. This is on Win 10 x64 fully up to date (no preview ring)

Comment: @Ramhound I have been using Acronis products for over a decade. Not one single time, out of the almost dozen times I've contacted them, they solved the issue. The tech support guys at Acronis who can do more than follow a flowchart of questions/suggestions take days to call you and then call you at odd hours. Either I gave up or solved the issue myself over that period of time (weeks).

Comment: That is an implicit no.